# React and Firebase useEffect does not update the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

This is the first time I try to use React Native (expo) with FireBase, and I have many difficulties on async calls.

now I'm trying to retrieve some data with 2 calls to FireBase (I don't know if this is correct).

```
useEffect(() => {
let isMounted = true;
if (isMounted) {
  let exercies1 = {};
  db.ref("trainings_exercies/" + trainingID + "/exercies").on(
    "value",
    (snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot && snapshot.val()) {
        Object.keys(snapshot.val()).map((e) => {
          db.ref("exercies/" + e).on("value", (snapshot) => {
            for (let key in snapshot.key) {
              exercies1[snapshot.key] = snapshot.val();
            }
            setExerciesList(exercies1);
            console.log("---> ", exercies1);
          });
        });
      }
    }
  );
}
return () => {
  isMounted = false;
};
}, []);
```

and I have this in my return:

```
{console.log("exercies", exerciesList)}
```

this is the console, the component first prints the console log inside the return, but then when it sets the new status, it does not update the component:
[image]

only the e001 element has been added before moving forward.

how can I fix this? and how can I handle calls to FireBase so that I wait for an answer before setting the statuses?

thank you very much for your help,
if you need more information, I can also upload the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

The last line of your code `}, []);` that empty array `[]` makes the useEffect hook to run only once.

As far as I can tell I don't see you are use a state object, in you were you could call useEffect at the end like `}, [state]);` and it will be triggered every time the state changes.

Try removing the `[]` from the hook, it should make react re-render the component if it detects a change.

The line

```js
return () => {
  isMounted = false;
};
```

Is a cleanup method that will only be triggered once the component is discarted/unmounted so the code inside the useEffect hooks will never get isMounted = false

Most of this is very well documented on the [react website](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, now works, only now it always enters the useEffect method.
and print endless console logs